# What are the 4 Dig Vijayas conquered by Karna?

Tags: mahabharata, karna

What exactly are Dig Vijayas and what are the campaigns that lead to Karna attaining the 4 Dig Vijayas?

Comment: The Army of Dwarka was the most potent army at the time it conquered the whole of India TWICE. Please read the Garga Samhita composed by Maharishi Garga.

Answer (score 6):

The word *Dig Vijaya* means a victory campaign. A king along with his forces invades their foes. The defeated king should pay a great amount of gold, taxes and tribute and should accept the victorious king as monarch. When Yudhushtira was a monarch before the exile, his brothers toured all the directions and conquered kingdoms.

Karna started his victory campaign on behalf of Duryodhana when Pandavas were living in the forests. This happened after the ghosha yatra in which Duryodhana was liberated from the Gandharvas by the Pandavas. After that incident, Duryodhana had returned to Hastinapura. Bhishma Pitamaha speaks some harsh words against Karna and advises Duryodhana to make peace with the Pandavas. Duryodhana laughs at Bhishma and leaves that place along with his counsellors. Karna who was unhappy with Bhishma Pitamaha's words [said](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03251.htm):

> 'O Kuru's son, Duryodhana, do thou lay to heart tie words that I say. Bhishma always blameth us, and praiseth the Pandavas. And from the ill-will he beareth towards thee, he hateth me also. And, O lord of men, in thy presence he ever crieth me down. I shall never, O Bharata, bear these words that Bhishma had said in thy presence in relation to this matter, extolling the Pandavas, and censuring thee, O represser of foes! Do thou, O king, enjoin on me, together with servants, forces, and cars. I shall, O monarch, conquer the earth furnished with mountains and woods and forests. **The earth had been conquered by the four powerful Pandavas. I shall, without doubt, conquer it for thee single-handed. Let that wretch of the Kuru race, the exceedingly wicked-minded Bhishma, see it,**--he who vilifies those that do not deserve censure, and praises those that should not be praised. Let him this day witness my might, and blame himself. Do thou, O king, command me. **Victory shall surely be thine.** By my weapon, O monarch, I swear this before thee.'

By hearing the words of Karna, Duryodhana replies with great delight:

> 'I am blessed. I have been favoured by thee,--since thou, endued with great strength, art ever intent on my welfare. My life hath borne fruit, to-day. **As thou, O hero, intendest to subdue all our enemies, repair thou**. May good betide thee! O subduer of foes, having been thus addressed by Dhritarashtra's intelligent son, Karna ordered all the necessaries for the excursion. And on an auspicious lunar day, at an auspicious moment, and under the influence of a star presided over by an auspicious deity, that mighty bowman, having been honoured by twice-born ones, and been bathed with auspicious and holy substances and also worshipped by speech set out, filling with the rattle of his car the three worlds, with their mobile and immobile objects."

The details of his victory campaign are explained in [chapter 252](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03252.htm) of Vanaparva.

He toured all the directions *viz*  east, west, north and south to complete the Digvijaya yatra and he conquered all his enemies.

> Vaisampayana continued, "Then, O bull among the Bharatas, that mighty bowman, Karna, surrounded by a large army, besieged the beautiful city of Drupada. And he, after a hard conflict, brought the hero under subjection, and, O best of monarchs, made Drupada contribute silver and gold and gems, and also pay tribute. And, O foremost of kings, having subdued him, (Karna) brought under subjection those princes that were under him (Drupada) and made them pay tribute. Then going to the north, he subdued the sovereigns (of that quarter) and having effected the defeat of Bhagadatta, Radha's son ascended that mighty mountain Himavat, all along fighting his foes. And ranging all sides, he conquered and brought under subjection all the kings inhabiting the Himavat, and made them pay dues. Then descending from the mountain and rushing to the east, he reduced the Angas, and the Bangas, and the Kalingas, and the Mandikas, and the Magadhas. the Karkakhandas; and also included with them the Avasiras, Yodhyas, and the Ahikshatras. Having (thus) conquered the eastern quarter Karna then presented himself before Batsa-bhumi. And having taken Batsa-bhumi, he reduced Kevali, and Mrittikavati, and Mohana and Patrana, and Tripura, and Kosala,--and compelled all these to pay tribute. Then going to the south, Karna vanquished the mighty charioteers (of that quarter) and in Dakshinatya, the Suta's son entered into conflict with Rukmi. After having fought dreadfully, Rukmi spake to the Suta's son saying, 'O foremost of monarchs, I have been pleased with thy might and prowess. I shall not do thee wrong: I have only fulfilled the vow of a Kshatriya. Gladly will I give thee as many gold coins as thou desirest.' Having met with Rukmi, Karna, repaired to Pandya and the mountain, Sri. And by fighting, he made Karala, king Nila, Venudari's son, and other best of kings living in the southern direction pay tribute. Then going to Sisupala's son, the son of the Suta defeated him and that highly powerful one also brought under his sway all the neighbouring rulers. And, O bull of the Bharata race, having subjugated the Avantis and concluded peace with them, and having met with the Vrishnis, he conquered the west. And, having come to the quarter of Varuna, he made all the Yavana and Varvara kings pay tribute. And, having conquered the entire earth--east, west, north and south--that hero without any aid brought under subjection all the nations of the Mlechchhas, the mountaineers, the Bhadras, the Rohitakas, the Agneyas and the Malavas. And, having conquered the mighty charioteers, headed by the Nagnajitas, the Suta's son brought the Sasakas and the Yavanas under his sway. Having thus conquered and brought under his subjection the world, the mighty charioteer and tiger among men came (back) to Hastinapura. That lord of men, Dhritarashtra's son, accompanied by his father and brothers and friends, came to that mighty bowman, who had arrived, and duly paid homage unto Karna crowned with martial 
>   merit.

In the above way, Karna conquered all the kingdoms and submitted all the gold and tribute gained in the invasion to the Monarch Duryodhana.

Answer (score 4):

Over the years (ever since 2014) i have heard several absurd claims being made about Karna's digvijaya. Some say he conquered the world, others say he only conquered a few kingdoms, some say he conquered just second rate kings, others even say that Karna just defeated one king and then started to believe that he conquered the whole world. People say that the critical edition (BORI) removed this incident. But none of these claims are true.

For this reason, I am making this post to clear all doubts and hopefully put an end to the spread of so much misinformation.

[image: Image of Aryavarta/Bharatvarsh (during Mahabharata times)]
***Image of Aryavarta/Bharatvarsh (during Mahabharata times)***

**Question: What did BORI do?**
**Answer:** Bori basically skipped Karna's digvijaya.
**Explanation:** The digvijaya was supposed to be recited during the Vana Parva (right after Ghosha-Yatra). But when Duryodhana tells Karna that he wishes to replicate the Rajasuya Yajna Sacrifice (of the Pandavas) then the text shows that Karna says all the monarchs of the earth have been conquered by Duryodhana. And are now under his rule.

[image: screenshot]

**Now does it make any sense? If Karna did a digvijaya why would BORI remove it?**
**Explanation:** Now Duryodhana says he wants to perform the Rajasuya sacrifice but Karna says as long as Yudhishthira & Dhritarashtra are alive we cannot ever perform this sacrifice. So he recommends to do the Vaishnava sacrifice. Duryodhana agrees and orders the construction of a golden plough. It gets created by artisans, then Duryodhana sends messengers to invite kings and Brahamanas to the sacrifice. Duhsasana sends a messenger to the Pandavas who reject the invitation.

**The evidence for Karna's digvijaya mentioned by Bhishma on 10th night**
[image: screenshot]

**Analysis:** On the 10th night Bhishma says that Karna single-handedly went to some kings capital, and defeated all the kings their in a battle, all for the sake of Duryodhana. I do not know what incident Bhishma is talking about, but it's safe to say that whatever Bhishma said on the tenth night to Karna was just a political move by Bhishma for one last attempt to avert the war. Because in this above screenshot you can clearly read what he says. This quote probably was not even about the conquest of Karna. The next one actually mentions his digvijaya though.

**11th day**
[image: screenshot]

**Analysis:** Note that Bhishma claims that Nagnajit was the king that was the forefront (most important and leading king) who was defending the kingdoms that were attacked by Karna. As per Bhishma Karna conquered the Ambhashthas, Videhas, Gandharas, Kiratas and the people who lived in the Himalayan territories. On the eleventh day, Bhishma blesses Karna & tells him to fight.

**Mentioned by Dhritarashtra**
[image: screenshot]

**Analysis:** This is the strongest of evidence that Karnians have. Dhritarashtra said that Karna is the one who defeated powerful enemies who were extremely difficult to vanquish. He tells this to Sanjaya and then goes on to make a list of the tribes Karna conquered. You can read it in the above screenshot, but i might as well be your story teller here:

1. Gandharas
2. Madrakas
3. Matsyas
4. Trigartas
5. Tanganas
6. Shakas
7. Panchalas
8. Videhas
9. Kunindas
10. Kashis
11. Kosalas
12. Suhmas
13. Angas
14. Pundras
15. Nishadas
16. Vangas
17. Kichakas
18. Vatsas
19. Kalingas
20. Taralas
21. Ashmakas
22. Rishikas

**Analysis continued:** Dhritarashtra even claims that Karna vanquished them using physical strength. Did Karna suddenly become a Bhima 2.0? This statement is clearly an exaggeration made up by Dhritarashtra. He's basically saying Karna fought twenty-two wars/battles and won all of them. And they were against all of these tribes/kingdoms (call them whatever you want but they were groups of people that ruled a lot of land in ancient India). I could argue that Dhritarashtra was talking about who was defeated by Karna during the Kurukshetra war, but that wouldn't make sense now would it? Because Kichaka and his brothers did not participate in the war (they were all killed much before), so how could Karna defeat them? I think the obvious conclusion is that due to the death of Karna and the defeat of his sons in the war, Dhritarashtra (out of sorrow and grief) started to paint Karna as defeating warriors that he never defeated. This statement was complete exaggeration by Dhritarshtra and should not be taken literally.

**Mentioned by Shalya**
[image: screenshot]

**Analysis:** As per Shalya he only conquered 5 enemies (Videha, Ambhastha, Kamboja, Nagnajit & Gandhara).

**What did Karna & Duryodhana really do?**
**Answer:** They performed the Vaishnava Yajna (sacrifice) 
This sacrifice had only ever been performed by the ancient one known as "Vishnu". The original vedic Vishnu not the current mythical Vishnu.
This sacrifice boasted of being equal to the Rajasuya Yajna sacrifice.
They conquered a handful kingdoms (that had many many kings). And forced them all to pay tribute and participate in their sacrifice aka Yajna. They did not conquer the whole earth, world etc. They did not even conquer all of Bharatvarsh & Aryavarta.

Even if they did then also it's no big feat as other warriors have done the same in the past before them.

**According to Bhishma**

According to the Grand-sire only 5 wars were won by Karna (in the Digvijaya). He also says the most important king defeated by Karna is Nagnajit.

**Warriors defeated by Karna**

1. *The Kamvojas*

   Rajapura was the capital of the Kamboja kingdom. On Duryodhana’s behalf, Karna led an expedition there. Karna seiged Rajapura and killed most of the warriors of the Kambhoja clan. The Kamvojas lived in the hindu kush mountains (modern day Afghanistan). They were kind of like the Indian version of mongols and Huns.

   I guess Karna fans can be proud of this achievement. Because the conquest of Afghanistan is a feat that has only been repeated by Alexander the Great & Genghis Khan. Not to mention the Pandavas themselves. Even USA & Russia failed to conquer Afghanistan.

   In Drona Parva this is how they are described
   [image: screenshot]

   But then again, do not forget that this victory is not impressive at all, the Kamvojas have been conquered many times over by people before Karna and after Karna.
2. *The Videhas*

   Videha has a capital called Mithila. This is the same country that was ruled by Janaka (the father of Sita from Ramayana). So i guess we can give Karna some props for this.
3. *King Nagnajit*

   Unknown king only mentioned twice, by Shalya and Bhishma. That too when talking to Karna. So he could be an interpolated character, nothing is told about him and he is only mentioned to make Karna look good.
4. *Himalayas*

   Karna went to the roof of the world (the Himalayas) and conquered everyone who lived their. Although the term everyone may be an exaggeration made by Bhishma.
5. *Kiratas*

   They were people who are skilled in warfare, they were mountaineers, and lived in the Himalayas protected by fortresses. However they were divided into many groups, Bhagadatta was just one of their 8 (eight) kings. And Karna only conquered two tribes of the Kiratas, not all Kiratas. Show me the narrative that says Karna conquered all of them.
6. *Ambhasthas*

   These people lived in Lahore (modern day Pakistan) lol. The same country that has been defeated by India in many wars. So what is the bravery in defeating them?

   Here is some more information about them - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambashtha
7. *Gandhara lands*

   Strange as it may seem but Karna held a beef with the Gandharas too (Sakuni & Gandhari's tribe). He conquered them in his digvijay, their is sufficient proof for this. Perhaps he is the one who killed Sakuni's father (Soubala).

   During his famous conversation (flame war or debate?) with Shalya in the Karna Parva, it is found out that he considered the Gandharas an uncivilized people. That Karna was racist towards Gandharas.
8. *Magadha*

   Girivraja was the capital of Magadha and is now in modern day Bihar.
   But is it not odd that the same Magadha who's previous lord (Jarasandha) was defeated by Karna long ago is now engaging in a second conflict with Karna? This leads me to doubt that Karna even defeated Jarasandha then. Why would Karna have to defeat the same dynasty twice? Does it make any sense?

#### Misconceptions about the digvijaya

1. **Misconception #1**
   Karna conquered the whole world

   **Clarification:**
   No he did not, that is the dumbest claim any Karna fan could make. If Karna conquered the whole world where are the monuments to give testimony to his great world conquest? Did he conquer the Americas? Australia? Canada? He did not even conquer all of India. Let alone the whole earth.

   Even if we consider Dhritarashtra's statement (because he is the one who lists the most amount of victims for the conquest of Karna), then it still would not be true. Because Dhritarahstra did not include Raksasas tribes in his fairy tale list.

   Perhaps Karna only conquered four to five kingdoms, if he conquered one kingdom for every direction then he may be able to make big claims like he own the whole earth because he conquered one kingdom for the south another for the east a third for the north one more for the west etc. Because that meant he conquered all directions.

   But that would just prove that the statement of KMG Mahabharata is a hyperbole and symbolism. That if you conquer one state like Punjab in India, then you can claim that you won all of India because you conquered one state of India.
2. **Misconception #2**
   Karna defeated all Gandharvas led by Chitrasena and he made Chitrasen bow to him...

   **Clarification:**
   No such incident has ever been mentioned in the Mahabharata.

   Nowhere has it been stated that Karna fought any Gandharva during his digvijaya yatra.

   Karna's conquest is mentioned 3 times, first by Bhishma, then by Shalya, and lastly by Dhritarashtra. None of these three ever mentioned an encounter where Karna won against Gandharvas.

   The Gandharas are mentioned but the Gandharvas are not. Theya re not the same the Gandharvas are different from Gandharas.

   Also just the name of the tribe is not enough, show me the name of Chitrasena being subjugated.
3. **Misconception #3**
   Karna defeated Shalya and conquered the Madrakas

   **Clarification:**
   Karna and Shalya had many arguments in Karna Parva. Karna even threatened to kill Shalya but never reminded Shalya of this so-called defeat he suffered at the hands of Karna in the Digvijaya. Is it not strange?

   Prior to the death of Duhsasana, Karna is depressed, then Shalya (in order to cheer Karna up) talked to him about several kingdoms that were conquered by him (by Karna). But he never mentions that Karna conquered the Madra kingdom. That he conquered Shalya's kingdom the tribe of Madrakas etc.

   Karna bragged to his own brother Bhima about how he had defeated him, so he would surely brag about his achievements in the Digvijaya. This was an opportune moment to brag to Shalya about his conquest, but no he didn't, probably because it never happened!
4. **Misconception #4**
   Karna defeated Drupada and the Panchalas (including Dhrishtadyumna & Srikandi). Karna did this alone but it took all the Pandavas to combine their powers together to defeat the same Drupad.

   **Clarification:**
   First of all this statement is only partially true. The Drupad who was defeated by Karna was a very old Drupada. It has been almost 60 years ever since the guru dakshina incident of Adi Parva. Drupada was clearly not the same man that he used to be. He was not that great warrior anymore who could best all Kourava princes, defeat all sons of Dhritarashtra, and vanquish even the mighty champion of the Suta race (brave Karna). He was far past his prime and saw no reason to even improve his skills or keep up with the big dogs. Because he had three right hand warriors who were his generals, Srikandi (slayer of Bhishma), Drishtadyumna (slayer of Drona) & Satyajit (considered equal to Arjuna in archery).

   Secondly it did not take all the Pandavas to defeat Drupada. It only took Arjuna to defeat Drupad. So it only took one Pandava to beat Drupada. Not all five of them. Yudhishthira did not participate in the war. Nakula and Sahadeva were laying waste to the capital during the time that Arjuna defeated Drupada. And Bhima was killed all of the Pancala soldiers. So no it did not take all of them, only one of the Pandava's was more than enough. To defeat the person that was more of a man than all one hundred Kouravas and Karna.

   Also, this incident remains doubtful. It's very questionable if this even happened. Because the Pancalas (who were supposedly conquered by Karna for Duryodhana's sacrifice) lent their support to the Pandavas (the very sworn enemies of Duryodhana) in the war of Kurukshetra.

   Lastly, the only one (in BORI) who says that Karna conquered Panchala is Dhritarashtra. And he only said that out of sorrow and grief once he discovered how Karna died. It is shameless glorifying of warriors who died in Kurukshetra. Same glorifying was done after Bhishma's death & Abhimanyu's death. Even Sanjaya over glorifies Ghatotkaca (after his death) to the point of saying he killed a whole Aukshouni of the Kurus by falling on them with his dead body. It's absurd, ridiculous, and impossible. Same thing with Karna, here Dhritarashtra shows affection for Karna after his death (probably only because of his friendship with the favorite son Duryodhana).

   Basically Karna fans overrated Karna's adversary only to make Karna's achievement seem bigger than it actually is. All Karna did was defeat an old Drupada (who was near his deathbed), a eunuch (Srikandi), a inexperienced prince (Drishtadyumna), and another overrated old man (Satyajit). I don't see any supernatural achievement that Karna did here. No comparison with the mighty Pandava prince Arjuna. And it's possible that this incident did not even occur in Mahabharata. And even it did then it's not impressive. It does not make him superior to any Pandava.
5. **Misconception #5**
   Karna conquered all the Vrishnis (even Satyaki and Krishna lol)

   **Clarification:**
   Please Karna fans do not make such jokes, please! Krishna (during Vana Parva) vowed that the earth shall drink the blood of Karna and Duryodhana. Karna was not so powerful that he could defeat Krishna and conquer his kingdom. Such a foolish theory has never been made before. Like really? Krishna was baying for Karna's blood. Krishna is one of the three supreme archers of the Mahabharata (the other two being Arjuna & Satyaki).

   In Harivamsa (also written by Vyasa) when Karna fight side by side with Jarasandha to complete the conquest of the Vrishnis of Dwaraka, Karna is tied up with a rope and thrown into a cave by Pradyumna (Rukmini's son). It is given in Harivamsa chapter 84, what happened when Karna attacked Dwarka. And this was much before Vana Parva. So Karna would not dare to do such a mistake again.

   Pradyumna (a little kid) defeated him and beat him up. He would never want to be humiliated like that again.

   Krishna would never accept Duryodhana's rule over Dwaraka.

   As for defeating Satyaki. Such a feat could only be accomplished in Karna's dreams. **Read this post** - https://logicastra.blogspot.com/2017/05/karna-vs-satyaki.html it has been explained how Satyaki defeated Karna ten times. Even on the 17th day Karna was no match for the ace archer Satyaki.
6. **Misconception #6**
   Karna defeated Ekalavya of the Nishadas

   **Clarification:**
   Leave aside BORI Mahabharata even KMG Mahabharata does not mention the name of Ekalavya anywhere in the digvijaya chapter of Karna. Just the word Nishadas is not enough. Do you not understand?

   Why would Karna even attack the Nishadas? Why would he fight Ekalavya? Jarasandha was a friend of Karna's and Ekalavya was a servant of Jarasandha. So Karna would be in Ekalavya's good books. So why would their be any conflict between them?

   If Ekalavya was subjugated by Karna then how come in the Udyoga Parva he was sent a message to lend support to the Pandavas? This must mean that Ekalavya was going to fight against the Kurus, and against Karna in the war of Kurukshetra. So how could Drupada send an appeal for help to a person like Ekalavya (who was supposedly under the rule of the Kouravas)?

   Drupad is not a fool, he would never send a request for help from someone who has accepted the rule of Duryodhana.

   Also I would like to point out that Ekalavya was only the member of one tribe of Nishadas, their were multiple tribes of Nishadas. We don't know which Nishadas were conquered by Karna.

   The only character who states Karna defeated the Nishadas, is Dhritarashtra. He said it in a emotional moment after he learned about the defeat of Duryodhana n the war, the deaths of Duhasana and Karna etc.

   Other than Dhritarashtra's statement their is no reference for this incident ever happening. So we can only conclude that Karna never defeated any Nishadas prior to the war of Kurukshetra. And by that time Ekalavya was already dead (he died at the hands of Krishna before the war).
7. **Misconception #7**
   Karna defeated Bhagadatta and conquered all the Kirata tribes

   **Clarification:**
   No Karna did not defeat Bhagadatta. Such an incident has only been mentioned in KMG Mahabharata (with no cross reference to it, so lack of proof in their too). It was removed as an interpolation by BORI.

   Nowadays Karna fans logic is that because Karna defeated and subjugated the Kiratas, that mean he defeated & subjugated Bhagadatta also. Because Bhagadatta was a chief of the Kiratas. I'll have you all know that even Bhima had defeated the seven kings of Kirata (their were seven kirata kings and all of them were subjugated by Bheema). But none of his fans say that Bima defeated Bhagadatta, because they know that their favorite character and warrior had limits unlike Karna fans.

   Bhishma said that Karna brought the Kiratas (and everyone who lived in the Himalayas) under Duryodhana's rule. But that is not enough to say that Karna defeated Bhagadatta because his name is not mentioned anywhere. And if a prominent monarch like Bhagadatta was defeated and had his kingdom conquered then it would not remain hidden, it would be stated clearly in the text. but it isn't. So Karna did not defeat Bhagadatta either.

   Bhagadatta was also stated to be the lord of those beings who dwelt alongside the ocean shores not the Himalayas.
8. **Misconception #8**
   Karna conquered the Matsya kingdom of Virata & Kichaka

   **Clarification:**
   No he didn't. Why did Karna not conquer this kingdom? Because when Kichaka dies then Susharman (a friend of Duryodhana) comes to Hastinapore and proposes that they attack the Matsya kingdom as Virata would be powerless without Kichaka. To regain the lost lands of Susharman, but if Karna conquered Matsya kingdom prior to this incident then they would have no need for another war with the Matsyas. It would already be under Karna's grip so it is clear as water that Karna never achieved this feat. He never conquered this kingdom.

   It also proves that Karna was weaker than Kichaka since they were all afraid of Kichaka and never dared to attack the Matsya kingdom as long as Kichaka was alive.

   Only person who said Karna conquered Kichaka is Dhritarashtra. And that too only in grief when he heard the news of Karna's death he said so. But here is a screenshot form BORI Mahabharata which will prove that Karna was waiting for this opportune moment where his enemy the mighty Kichaka would die so that he can conquer Matsya.

   Proof that Kichaka was an enemy of the Kouravas
   [image: screenshot]

   **Analysis:** Over here the word enemy is clearly used.

   Proof that Karna wanted to conquer Matsyadesh of Virata
   [image: screenshot]

   *Analysis:** What i would like to know is why did Karna & Duryodhana not make such an attempt to raid the Matsyas during the digvijaya? This clearly contradicts Dhritarashtra's claim of Karna defeating the Matsyas. Also what about when Kripa asked Karna what he has achieved? Then at that time Karna has no answer, this was during Virata Parva. That Parva is after Vana Parva (where Karna is supposed to have done the digvijay). They should have mentioned how Karna subjugated this land before, but since they did not, that means it's quite obvious that Karna never conquered Matsya, Karna never defeated Virata and Kichaka & Upakichakas.

#### Conclusions

- Karna did not conquer the world or earth.
- Karna did not conquer whole of India.
- Most reporters (Shalya & Bhishma the only unbiased ones) agree that Karna only defeated 5 opponents.
- Karna never defeated any Nishadas in his digvijay.
- Karna did not defeat any army called Narayani sena.
- Karna did not conquer Dwaraka.
- Karna did not conquer the Vrishnis.
- Karna did not fight any Gandharvas in his campaign.
- So he did not avenge his ghosha yatra defeat.
- Karna did not ever conquer Matsya kingdom.
- Karna was scared of Kichaka's brothers and he feared Kichaka.
- Karna did not conquer Shalya and the Madra kingdom either.
- Karna did not defeat Jayadratha.
- Karna only conquered Videha, Nagnajit, Gandhara, Ambhasta, Kamvoja etc.
- Duryodhana performed a sacrifice that only Vishnu ever performed.

Answer (score 3):

http://karna-the-great.blogspot.com/p/digvijay-of-karna.html

Karna defeated, Drupada, Bhagadatta, a powerful warrior who fought for Kauravas because Karna conquered him, all kings inhabiting himavat, all kings of himalaya, shing to the east, he reduced the Angas, and the Bangas, and the Kalingas, and the Mandikas, and the Magadhas. the Karkakhandas; and also included with them the Avasiras, Yodhyas, and the Ahikshatras, rukmi, nila, Mlechchhas, the mountaineers, the Bhadras, the Rohitakas, the Agneyas and the Malavas. And, having conquered the mighty charioteers, headed by the Nagnajitas, Shishupal's son, Yavana & varvara.

●Victory over NORTH direction :
Sacred-Text :
Then going to the north, he subdued the sovereigns (of that quarter) and having effected the defeat of Bhagadatta, Radha's son ascended that mighty mountain Himavat, all along fighting his foes. And ranging all sides, he conquered and brought under subjection all the kings inhabiting the Himavat, and made them pay dues.

→ CONCLUSION :

a) In north, Karna single-handlydefeated Bhagdatta (son of Narkasur)
[ Note- In kurushetra war, when this bhagdatta launched Vaishnavastra then krishna saved Arjuna by enduring the weapon on his own chest. But In digvijay karna easily defeated him without help of anyone. LOL..This again proves Karna > Arjuna ]

b) After that he went to himalaya & gain victory over all kings of himalaya.

Victory over WEST direction :
Sacred-Text :
"Then, O bull among the Bharatas, that mighty bowman, Karna, surrounded by a large army, besieged the beautiful city of Drupada. And he, after a hard conflict, brought the hero under subjection, and, O best of monarchs, made Drupada contribute silver and gold and gems, and also pay tribute. And, O foremost of kings, having subdued him, (Karna) brought under subjection those princes that were under him (Drupada) and made them pay tribute.

→CONCLUSION :

a) Drupad was the first warrior defeated by Karna in his digvijay. Point to be noted here: All Pandavas collectively defeated Drupad, while Karna did it single handedly.

b) Karna defeated drupad & all kings of west direction.

Victory over EAST direction :
Sacred-Text :
Then descending from the mountain and rushing to the east, he reduced the Angas, and the Bangas, and the Kalingas, and the Mandikas, and the Magadhas. the Karkakhandas; and also included with them the Avasiras, Yodhyas, and the Ahikshatras. Having (thus) conquered the eastern quarter Karna then presented himself before Batsa-bhumi. And having taken Batsa-bhumi, he reduced Kevali, and Mrittikavati, and Mohana and Patrana, and Tripura, and Kosala,--and compelled all these to pay tribute.

→ CONCLUSION :

a) In east, Karna defeated all king including Angas, bangas, kalingas, mandikas,magdhas & karkalhandas, avasiras, yodhyas & ahishastras.

b) There was Batsa-bhoomi where Rakshashas (Monsters) were living n people were irritated by them. Karna destroyed all rakshasas giving freedom to people.

c) Then Karna started to destroy all Rakshashas(monster) in east & their kingdom including Kevali, mrittikevali, mohana, patrana, Tripura & konasa.

Victory over SOUTH direction :
Sacred-Text :
Then going to the south, Karna vanquished the mighty charioteers (of that quarter) and in Dakshinatya, the Suta's son entered into conflict with Rukmi. After having fought dreadfully, Rukmi spake to the Suta's son saying, 'O foremost of monarchs, I have been pleased with thy might and prowess. I shall not do thee wrong: I have only fulfilled the vow of a Kshatriya. Gladly will I give thee as many gold coins as thou desirest.' Having met with Rukmi, Karna, repaired to Pandya and the mountain, Sri. And by fighting, he made Karala, king Nila, Venudari's son, and other best of kings living in the southern direction pay tribute. Then going to Sisupala's son, the son of the Suta defeated him and that highly powerful one also brought under his sway all the neighbouring rulers. And, O bull of the Bharata race, having subjugated the Avantis and concluded peace with them, and having met with the Vrishnis, he conquered the west. And, having come to the quarter of Varuna, he made all the Yavana and Varvara kings pay tribute.

→ CONCLUSION :

a) In south, Karna single-handly defeated Rukhmi(Brother Of Rukhamini), Pandya(enemy of krishna), nila & other all kings of south.

### b) Then Karna vanquished Shishupal's son, Yavana & varvara & many other.

Karna Conquered WHOLE EARTH :
Sacred-Text :
And, having conquered the entire earth--east, west, north and south--that hero without any aid brought under subjection all the nations of the Mlechchhas, the mountaineers, the Bhadras, the Rohitakas, the Agneyas and the Malavas. And, having conquered the mighty charioteers, headed by the Nagnajitas, the Suta's son brought the Sasakasand the Yavanasunder his sway. Having thus conquered and brought under his subjection the world, the mighty charioteer and tiger among men came (back) to Hastinapura.

→ CONCLUSION :

a) After victory in all 4 directions, Karna easily won all remaining regions including Mlechecheas, bhadras, rohitakas, agneyas, malavas, sasakasand, yavanasunder & many others.

Comment: We [insist](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277) on citing some authentic sources while answering questions. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) you can find link to useful resources to get scriptures (shastras).

Answer (score 1):

BORI eliminated how it was that Karna conquered all Aryavart, but it is not interpolation. Since there are cross references for your Digvijaya:

Dronabisheka Parva chapter 981 (4)

> Sanjaya said, "When I spoke in this way, the aged grandfather of the Kurus heard him. His
>   mind was delighted and I spoke words that were appropriate to the time and the place.
>   'May you be established amidst your well-wishers, like the ocean among rivers, the sun
>   among all stellar bodies, truth among the virtuous, fertile ground among seeds and clouds
>   among all beings. May your relatives depend on you, like the immortals on the one with a
>   thousand eyes.19 Through the strength of your own arms and your value, you did what
>   brought pleasure to Dhritarashtra's are. O Karna! You went to Rajapura and killed the Kambojas.20 You went to Girivraja21 and vanquished the kings, with Nagnajit at the
>   forefront, and the Ambashthas, the Videhas and the Gandharas. O Karna! In earlier times, you
>   He brought those who dwelt in the Himalayas and Kiratas, who were harsh in battle, under
>   Duryodhana's suzerainty. In every such place, you fought for Duryodhana's welfare. O brave
>   one! O Karna! You conquered many greatly energetic ones.

Source: Jayadratha Vadha Parva chapter 1043 (66)

> O great king! Jaya, Satvata Kritavarma, the king of Kamboja 32 and Shrutayu countered Dhananjaya. They had ten thousand rathas as their followers-the Abhishahas, the Shurasenas, the Shibis, the Vasatis, the Machellakas, the Lalitthyas, the Kekayas, the Madrakas, the Narayanas, the Gopalas and masses of Kambojas. They were revered as brave and had been previously vanquished by Karna.

Source: Karna Vadha Parva chapter 1155 (5)

> Dhritarashtra said, "O Sanjaya! Adhiratha's son was brave. He was like a lion or an elephant in his courage. His shoulders were like that of a bull. His eyes, gait and voice were like those of a bull. I was a bull and like a bull. He was young and was capable of understanding the vajra. He did not retreat from a battle, even if the adversary was to be the great Indra. Because of his bowstring twanging against his palms and because of the shower of his arrows, chariots, horses, men and elephants could not stand before him in a battle. He was mighty-armed and without decay. He was the slayer of large numbers of the enemy. Depending on him, Duryodhana ventured to provoke an enmity with the immensely strong sons of Pandu. How could Karna, best of rathas, have been brought down by Partha in the battle? I was capable of understanding that value is impossible to counter. How could that tiger among men have been killed? Depending on the strength of his own arms, he never showed any reverence towards Achyuta, 83 Dhananjaya or the Vrishnis. 'The wielders of the Sharnga and Gandiva bows 84 are undefeated. When they are together, on their divine chariot, I will alone bring them down in the battle. "I always spoke these words to the wicked and evil Duryodhana, who was afflicted by desire for the kingdom and was confused because of his greed for what It was undesirable. He is the one who defeated powerful enemies who were extremely difficult to vanquish-the Gandharas, the Madrakas, the Matsyas, the Trigartas, the Tanganas, the Shakas, the Panchalas, the Videhas, the Kunindas, the Kashis, the Kosalas, the Suhmas , the Angas, the Pundras, the Nishadas, the Vangas, the Kichakas, the Vatsas, the Kalingas, the Taralas, the Ashmakas and the Rishikas.

Explanation:

Karna conquered kingdoms that are the tip of the four directions of the ancient map of Aryavart: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5EJZ.jpg)

It is obvious that he conquered all the other kingdoms that were in those directions. This could be the reason why Dhritarashtra said that Karna conquered the whole world:

Source: Jayadratha Vadha Parva chapter 1083 (106)

> Oh son, how did Bhima fight with that son of Suta? Having remembered the many difficulties that the son of the suta had caused, how did Bhima fight with the son of the suta? The brave son of Suta conquered the entire world in one car.

The irony is that Bhima never defeated Karna, what did I base on this? Well, on the battlefield there is no defeat or return to battle, Satyaki fled from Drona on the 14th, but the same Dhritarashtra was mentioned by the undefeated Drona that same day, which also happened on the 13th.

Karna himself told Duryodhana that he conquered all the kings:

> Oh lord of men! Oh king, all the kings of the east, south, west and north pay tribute to you.
>
> All the lords of the earth have now been subjected to their subjugation. Summon the principal brahmanas and collect the offerings, according to the prescribed rites. Oh the best of the Kuru lineage! That all the ingredients and requirements for the sacrifice be collected. Oh king, oh destroyer of enemies! May the officiated priests summoned, learned in the Vedas, perform the rites in accordance with the sacred texts. Oh bull among the lineage of Bharata! Let your great sacrifice have much to eat and drink, and also be extremely prosperous, with all the qualities. "

The supporters of Duryodhana gave that their sacrifice was superior to Rajasuya:

> When sprinkling with fried grain and sandalwood powder, people said: "Oh, king, it is through good fortune that your sacrifice has been completed without any impediment." There were others present, who were not careful when speaking. They told the king: "Your sacrifice has not been equal to the sacrifice of Yudhishthira, it is not equivalent to a sixteenth part of that sacrifice." Thus, some, who were inconstant, spoke to the lord of man. : "Your sacrifice has surpassed all others.

Probably, it was superior and it was a sacrifice that only Vishnu could do. The Vishnu of the Mahabharata who was mentioned as a very important god from the beginning of Mahabharata, so Karna had to conquer all the kingdoms of the four directions

Comment: Pandu did a digvijaya, so did Krishna. All 4 pandavas did a digvijaya.

Comment: Kripacharya also asked karna what he has done and karna was silent. He had nothing to say.
Karna's digvijaya is nowhere near the amount that the Pandavas conquered.